# What caused Collibra to transition away from Collibra Connect?

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

As of Dec 2020 in the Collibra Marketplace many tools are showing an alert as to Connect... what would cause this and what impact does it have for Collibra developers? Can't seem to find further details as to the reasons, only signposts to documentation describing how to use the preferred API-based methods:

> We have made the decision to transition away from Collibra Connect so
> that we can better serve you and ensure you can use future product
> functionality without re-instrumenting or rebuilding integrations. For
> more information, please reach out to your Customer Success Manager.
>
> Learn more about different methods to build integrations in [Collibra
> Developer Portal](https://university.collibra.com/developer/connect/).

This example for Talend Data Lineage, just one of the many Connect tools:
[image: Collibra announcement/banner]

Answer (score 0):

Collibra's long-term direction is to transition away from Collibra Connect, which is an OEM of Mule ESB. Collibra provides native connectors to numerous source systems that vastly simplify integration and ingestion. The connectors not only ingest metadata but also provide additional value-added features such as data profiling, sampling and data classification, with more features to come in the future. Customers can also bring their ESB of choice, including Mulesoft, and work with Collibra's APIs to build integrations. For customers who choose to keep and use Mulesoft as their ESB, they will need to license directly with Mulesoft and can continue to use any integrations that they developed with Collibra Connect. Additionally, we are providing the Collibra Mulesoft Connector free of charge, so customers can continue to use it to build and maintain Mulesoft integrations going forward.